# Bash Scripting for highest and lowest number

Tags: bash

If I want my output to be - Highest number is 99 and Lowest number is -1

My bash script is called maxmin.sh that asks for 5 numbers as inputs ( 3 15 -1 99 22)

How can I write that in my bash script?

Comment: `man sort`, `man head` and `man tail`.

Comment: How does your script receive that input? That could be a necessary detail to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you should do your check in an [arithmetic context](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression):

```
if (( a > b )); then
    ...
fi
```